# Wordpress customization - which way to go?

Tags: php, wordpress, customization

I'm a senior .NET/C# developer and I would like to start a private-project in Wordpress. My PHP experiences are really out-of-date (10 years old) and I'm really confused: how to start?

It would be lame to use my (not existing) PHP 3.x or 4.x knowledge but I have no idea where to start.

So **what means Wordpress/PHP in 2012** for a senior but not senior php developer?

I found some starting points, what are you thinking about?

http://www.sitepoint.com/whats-new-php-5-3/

http://codex.wordpress.org/Site_Design_and_Layout

Please help me to change and extend this list. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you start with fiddling with the twenty eleven template.

the beautiful thing about wordpress functions is that they are all logically named. 
if you don't know what a function does just look if up in the codex and experiment with the results.

wordpress has its own api so your experience is still good.  you just have to know basics as foreach, variable types, functions and classes.

Them just experiment away.  That is the quickest easy to learn.

Comment: thank you. so nothing PHP5/6 speciality or any other "high end" php tricks needed?

Comment: nope wordpress is pretty straightforward and simple. usually its simple text manipulation, and those functions are well documented in the phpdocs.

when you want to write a really complicated plugin that does some really fancy stuff,  well,  you'll learn as you go.